# How to get the all table(s) name which are used in particular stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a requirement to get all the database tables name which are used in specific stored procedure?

**As an example,** I have one stored procedure as given below.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[my_sp_Name]
    @ID INT = NULL
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT ID, NAME, PRICE

    FROM tbl1
    INNER JOIN tbl2 ON tbl1.ProductId = tbl2.ProductId
    LEFT JOIN tbl3 ON tbl2.ProductSalesDate = tbl3.ProductSalesDate
    LEFT JOIN tbl4 ON tbl1.ProductCode = tbl4.ItemCode
END
```

**Expected output:**

Used_Table_Name

1. tbl1
2. tbl2
3. tbl3
4. tbl4

Can any one suggest a way?

Comment: `exec sp_depends [ProcedureName]`

Comment: @artm, Thanks for comment, Its return all type of database objects which are used. Also its not return the distinct value.

Comment: [Mansoor's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43177867/15498) would be a better choice since it doesn't use [*legacy views*](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190325(v=sql.110).aspx) that you shouldn't be using in any newly written code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below script to get table names in your store procedure :

```
  SELECT DISTINCT [object_name] = SCHEMA_NAME(o.[schema_id]) + '.' + o.name
        , o.type_desc
  FROM sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities ('[dbo].[Your_procedurename]',  
  'OBJECT')d
  JOIN sys.objects o ON d.referenced_id = o.[object_id]
  WHERE o.[type] IN ('U', 'V')
```

Answer (score 3):

Below query will help you to get used database tables in stored procedure.

```
;WITH stored_procedures AS (  
    SELECT oo.name AS table_name,  
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by o.name,oo.name ORDER BY o.name,oo.name) AS row  
    FROM sysdepends d  
    INNER JOIN sysobjects o ON o.id=d.id  
    INNER JOIN sysobjects oo ON oo.id=d.depid  
    WHERE o.xtype = 'P' AND o.name = 'my_sp_Name'
)  
SELECT Table_name AS 'Used_Table_Name' FROM stored_procedures  
WHERE row = 1
```